# I have a backup of the Wordpress folder but not the SQL database, is it possible for me to recover the website for local use?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, database-backups, mysql-backup

I have a backup of the entire Wordpress folder of one of my old websites but, unfortunately, I forgot to also make a backup of the database for it. It's been years since the website expired so there's no way I can get the SQL file that way, and both Wayback Machine and Google don't seem to have any caches left of it (a tutorial I saw mentioned trying that way).

Is it still possible for me to get the website working for local use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, depending on what you are willing to do.

**Is it still possible for me to get the website working for local use? No**

If you have no database you will not have access to the Posts, Pages, Users, Options and all of the meta.

**Is it still possible for me to get the website working for local use? Yes**

If you create all of the database entries again to your satisfaction. You will still have all of the images you can re-upload to recreate the database entries for images. Then just re-create all of the pages and users as needed. Plugins may need to be disabled/reactivated/reinstalled and configured as well as your theme settings.

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://web.archive.org/ , you might be in luck there. Without sqldump its not much to do. If you had a cache plugin active, check if you have any snapshots.

Comment: It only has one snapshot of the site and it shows me the error "Error. Page cannot be displayed. Please contact your service provider for more details. (1)" whenever I try to access it. I guess the site is just toast, then? :((